# Android parse special characters in json response

Tags: java, android, urlencode, json, android-parser

In my Android application I get JSON response string from a PHP url. from the response I get some hotel names with `apostrophe`, I get `&#039` character instead of `apostrophe`. How can I parse the hotel with special characters in android? `I can see the apostrophe in the browser but could not see in android logcat.`

I have tried `jresponse = URLEncoder.encode(jresponse,"UTF-8");` but I could not get `apostrophe` for hotel name.

This is the one of the hotel name in the response.

```
 I see the following in browser.

    {"id":12747,
     "name":"Oscar's",
     ....
    }
But in the logcat:

     id 12747
     name Oscar&#039;s
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [decoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLDecoder.html) instead of encoder. `URLDecoder.decode(jresponse,"UTF-8")`

Answer (score 0):

Use ISO-8859-2 when you create the URLEncodedEntity that you send off. You can set this as a parameter in the constructor.

Without a specified charset, you are probably sending the data in UTF-8/UTF-16 (most common) which the server is interpreting in a different way.

EDIT: It looks like ISO-8859-2 doesn't support ñ. You may have to change something server-side. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-2

Answer (score 0):

You can try Html class. eg :-
jresponse = Html.fromHtml(jresponse);